# Shell: Break both if and for loop at once

Tags: shell, shell-script, control-flow

Shell: Break both if and for loop at once.

My script: ip to name resolve code

```
IP=192.168.27.191
hostNameChecker()
{
    if [ `getent hosts $1 | wc -l` -ne 0 ];then
        HOST_NAME=`hostname`
        DNS_IP=`getent hosts $1 | cut -d " " -f 1 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'`
        DNS_NAMES=`getent hosts $1 | cut -d " " -f 2- | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'`
        for DNS_NAME in ${DNS_NAMES[@]} 
        do
            if [[ "$DNS_NAME" == "$HOST_NAME" ]];then
                    echo "Host name:$HOST_NAME and DNS_NAME:$DNS_NAME matched"
                    break 2;########Not working. only brakes inner for not outer if 
                else
                    continue;
                fi
        done
            echo "ERROR: Mismatch between DNS:$DNS_NAMES and Hostname:$HOST_NAME"
            exit 0  
    fi
}
hostNameChecker $IP
```

In the above script **break 2** only breaks inner for not outer if. 
I can add another if to solve it but is there any other possible way ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`break` has no effect on `if` statements.  In your use case, `return` will have the effect you're seeking, since there are no statements after the outer `if`, and `return` exits the function.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used `return 0;` instead of `break 2;`

Answer (score -1):

In C, you would use `goto`, in Bash we don't have [`goto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash) yet even if there was a similar language construct, this is [considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

So do it using another `if`.

Comment: What does C has to do with this?

Comment: @Bernhard: I just tried to include a supporting piece of information. What's the problem? If you think that's inapproriate there are tools for that in SA..

Comment: @Bernhard C => csh => shell - viola!